# Way to find clicked ListItem on ListWidget

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

I want to get ListItem in ListWidget that I clicked. But I can't find the way. All the things say get from text but I want the clicked one. Also  I'm new in qt and c++.

stackoverflow says add more detail but I don't know how to add more detail so I write this line to get enough "detail".

Here is my .h file:

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>
#include <string.h>
#include <QListWidgetItem>
QT_BEGIN_NAMESPACE
namespace Ui { class MainWindow; }
QT_END_NAMESPACE

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    MainWindow(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
    ~MainWindow();
    class rsu
    {
    public:
        std::string id;
        std::string name;
        double coorx;
        double coory;
        std::string ip;
        int port;

    };
    std::vector<rsu> r;
    QListWidgetItem *rsuitem;
private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;

private slots:
    void addRSU();
    void deleteRSU();

};
#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

And my .cpp file:

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include "string"
#include "string.h"
#include "QCheckBox"
#include "QString"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
    , ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    ui->rsuWidget->hide();
   connect(ui->addRSU, SIGNAL(clicked()), ui->rsuWidget, SLOT(show()));
   connect(ui->cancelRSU, SIGNAL(clicked()), ui->rsuWidget, SLOT(hide()));
   connect(ui->saveRSU, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(addRSU()));
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
    delete rsuitem;
}

void MainWindow::addRSU()
{
    rsu *baz = new rsu;
    baz->id = ui->ID->text().toStdString();
    baz->name = ui->Name->text().toStdString();
    baz->coorx = ui->CoorX->text().toFloat();
    baz->coorx = ui->CoorX->text().toFloat();
    baz->ip = ui->IP->text().toStdString();
    baz->port = ui->Port->text().toInt();
    r.push_back(*baz);
    rsuitem = new QListWidgetItem(QString::fromUtf8(baz->name.c_str()),ui->listRSU);
    rsuitem->setFlags(rsuitem->flags() | Qt::ItemIsUserCheckable);
    rsuitem->setCheckState(Qt::Unchecked);

}

void MainWindow::deleteRSU()
{

}
```

And my ui:

[image: UI Pic]

Comment: Your question is (to me at least) very unclear.  Are you just looking for something like the [`itemClicked`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlistwidget.html#itemClicked) signal?

Comment: Yes I'm looking sth lilke itemClicked but not a signal I looking for. I want to get item when I click it  like "Aaah you clicked item named "blabla" "

Comment: Then connect the signal to a custom slot and use a QMessageBox there to display 'Aaah you clicked item named'

Comment: what's the problem with the `itemClicked` signal as others suggested? Like `connect(ui->listRSU, &QListWidget::itemClicked, [this](QListWidgetItem *item) { QMessageBox::information(this, "Info", "You clicked " + item->text()); });`

Comment: I don't want to give item to any function I want function give me the item that I clicked

Comment: `"I want function give me the item that I clicked"`: and that's *exactly* what the [`itemClicked(QListWidgetItem *item)`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlistwidget.html#itemClicked) signal gives you.  If that's really not what you're looking for then you need to provide some more information.  Perhaps show the code you would *like* to be able to write -- even if it doesn't compile.

Comment: @MeteKorucu not sure but perhaps, you're misunderstanding how signals and slots work. Suppose there was a method returning the item which had been clicked. When are going to call this method? What if more than 1 item  had been clicked already. What should this method return in this case - the last clicked item or all of them? Instead of using such method you can use the signal-slot callback mechanism that gives you the clicked item (as a callback parameter) the moment it was clicked. If you need this item later you can save it in a member-variable, for example.

Comment: @MeteKorucu Note 1. "I don't want to give item to any function" - you don't give the item to the signal and you shouldn't call this signal yourself, it is called by `QListWidget` class in order to invoke the connected slot and pass the clicked item to you. Note 2. I said that you can store the clicked item for later use if you really need so. True, but I have to add that you should implement an additional guarantee that this item is not deleted/removed. `QListWidgetItem` is not a `QObject` and you can't use `QPointer` for it.